# Webpack code splitting - Automatically load all chunks by requesting a single chunk?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, electron, code-splitting

I'm using Webpack 4.x and have the following in my config:

```
splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
},
runtimeChunk: true
```

This results in three chunks in my project:

- app.prod.js
- 1.app.prod.js
- 2.app.prod.js

I'd like to load all three scripts using just one initial request. The reason for this is that I'd like to use the "preload" feature in Electron for security reasons, which accepts a single script.

Is there a way to have the initial `app.prod.js` require/import the additional chunks automatically?

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. I just load all the chunks manually. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: so annoying that it's not possible

Comment: I don't know that it's not possible, but if it is, nobody has shown up to say so.

Comment: Did you try the dynamic 'import()' syntax ?

Comment: It'll work, but refactoring everything into dynamic imports gonna be very annoying

Answer (score 1):

We were able to resolve this for our case with code like this:

Under `entry` you can split your project into "chunks" (using Webpack terminology) and then you can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to generate HTML files with the correct scripts for the given chunk automatically included.

```js
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
  },
  entry: {
    rendererA: `${basePath}/src/windowA/`,
    rendererB: `${basePath}/src/windowB/`,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(basePath, 'src/index.html'),
      chunks: ['rendererA'],
      filename: 'rendererA.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(basePath, 'src/index.html'),
      chunks: ['rendererB'],
      filename: 'rendererB.html',
    }),
  ]
```